# C# local copied variable value keep changing

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing this strange problem with strings.

I assigned a string like this:

```
string temp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s");
_snapShotTime = string.Copy(temp);

//here threads started....
//while thread progressing I am passing  _snapShotTime to create a directory.
//same in second threads.
```

But the time of local private variable `_snapShotTime` is keep on changing. I don't know why. I have used a local variable and copy value in it.

Thanks

Comment: Set a breakpoint on it, verify it only breaks *once*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your thread uses a lambda expression (or anonymous function) which *captures* `_snapShotTime`. That would indeed allow it to be changed. It's hard to say for sure without any code though.

If this *is* the problem, it's typically that you're referring to a captured variable which is declared outside the loop, but changed on every iteration of a loop. You can fix this by declaring a new variable which takes a copy of the original variable *inside* the loop, and only using that copy variable in the lambda expression. You'll get a "new" variable inside the loop on each iteration, so you won't have problems.

Comment: Sorry again, all comments delete

Comment: Jon I am assigning this variable before I start any threading.

Comment: @sunder: Well nothing's going to assign a new value to it without you making that assignment somewhere. It's really going to be impossible to help you further without seeing more code. Ideally, produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do

```
_snapShotTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s");
```

Also, place a breakpoint on that line and see when it is being called.

When it does break, see the stack and it will clarify things.

> I suspect that your threads change the value of _snapShotTime

Comment: I have used snapShotTime variable for assignment get not set.

I was using directly like this only then I thought its C# captured variable issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, they do not change unless a variable is reassigned to a new string.

We need to see more code in order to help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I do think so. But I can see this issue in front of me.